# MapFragment UI control buttons functional but invisible

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

### Solution:

The solution is that I had called `zOrderOnTop(true)` before to work around the [black flickering bug](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4639). In the face of this turnout of events I guess that the aforementioned bug does **not** have a valid workaround as of now. I tried the other suggestions in the thread, too, but none of them work without impairing the application

### Original problem:

In my application I want to display a map fragment nested inside another fragment which is not too big of a trouble with the newest API and Support Library. But the map shows some strange behaviour:

[image: Example map image]

As you might have noticed there are no buttons visible. The `plus` and `minus` buttons for zooming for example. But also the `myLocation` button seems to be gone. The interesting thing is: when I tap the screen in the top-right or bottom-right corner (where you might know they are supposed to be) the app does exactly what you would expect!

Since I am simply working alongside [the android maps api documentation tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map) I don't think that this is an issue of setting something visible. **I much rather assume that this has to do with the way that I show the fragment, some layer seems to get in the way. How can I fix this?**

Maybe someone here can spot my mistake, I would be very thankful!

**HostFragment**

```
public class HostFragment extends Fragment {

...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup res = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, null);

        // Build the MapFragment as a nested fragment into this one
        mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MAP);
        if (mMapFragment == null) {
            mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(mMapOptions);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.mapContainer, mMapFragment, MAP).commit();
        }

        // We can't be guaranteed that the map is available because Google Play services might not
        // be available. We'll check this again later on
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        return res;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Verify that the map is set up before presenting it to the user
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we haven't already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the MapFragment.
            mMap = mMapFragment.getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
            else {
                LOG.debug("Map is null");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the parameters for the map that will be displayed to the user
     */
    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }
}
```

**The host layout xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Best regards

**Updates:**
1: Using FrameLayout instead of RelativeLayout does *not* fix the problem
2: Setting the map type to NORMAL explicitely does *not* fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using [zOrderOnTop](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMapOptions.html#zOrderOnTop%28boolean%29)? In that case you won't see buttons. More info here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map?hl=pl#using_xml_attributes

Comment: YES that is it, thank you very much. I used `zOrderOnTop` before to fix the [black flickering bug](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4639), I will update my question with the solution and some thoughts on the bug in a second

Answer (score 2):

Try modifying the `setUpMap()` like below :

```
private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL); //added line
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true); //my code did not have these and still be able to display the zoom in, zoom out, and my location button
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
}
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Did you tested it on different devices with different api ? 2.x... 4.x ?
I had the same problem, so you have to dev your own buttons.

Comment: yes I did, tested on a 4.2.2, 4.0, 2.3.6 and on the emulator (4.2), all same behaviour

Comment: Ok, you have to do that:          gmaps.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

Comment: This doesn't fix it - and I wouldn't expect it to either. The buttons <b>are</b> enabled, they are simply <b>invisible</b>! But thanks for your input

Comment: Hmmm on your posted code, I just see the location button enabled, but no zoomcontrols. You have to enable them seperately. Please post you full code, if it is not.

Comment: I put it in after you recommended it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this documentation. You definetely miss to activate the zoom controls ;)

[gmaps v2 zoom controls](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/interactivity#zoom_controls)

Comment: Again: this is absolutely not the correct solution, why would the myLocation button not be visible either if this were correct? I put the line of code in that you recommended and - like expected - it has no effect, I'm sorry.
Also: please edit your answer instead of posting new ones, thank you

Comment: Unbelievable, I can reproduce it on my code! First my map behaves perfect. When I load other fragment and do some navigation, the controllers get invisible and I just see the map like you posted the image !?!?! I am checking that, maybe its the same problem.